# http_basic_authentication in request spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec-rails

I'm very confused about latest rspec versions. I've found several answers to this same question but being several years old they apparently don't work anymore.

I have a request spec that tests an endpoint that is behind `http_basic_authenticate_with`. I couldn't find a way to make this work.

My latest attempt is:

```
      it "returns data_services" do
        request.headers.merge!(authenticated_header(ENV.fetch('HTTP_USERNAME'), ENV.fetch('HTTP_PASSWORD')))
        get data_services_path
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
      end
```

Unfortunately there's no `request` object, which exists only after the `get` is performed. I've tried to pass the headers to the `get` method too, but no luck.
Is there any way to have requests specs for actions behing http simple auth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're in a request spec (recommended from Rails v5+), you need to pass your headers to the `get` method as a keyword argument:

```
get data_services_path, headers: authenticated_header(...)
```

The syntax you're trying with `request.headers` is for controller specs, and the rspec docs recommend [switching to request specs and not setting headers in controller specs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/setting-request-headers).

Comment: You don't actually need `params: {}` - the argument is tossed anyways if the hash is empty.